# Redux nested thunks, fetch from two different endpoints

Tags: react-native, redux-thunk

I would like to combine my `thunks` to get initial data for my app from `wordpress`, then get `tags` from another endpoint.

Here is my first action to get my `posts` (videos) json data:

```
export function fetchData() {
    const url = "http://app.rguc.co.uk/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts";

    return dispatch => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data) {
                    dispatch(fetchSuccessVideos(data));
                } else {
                    dispatch(fetchErrorVideos(data));
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
}
```

For each post I would like to get the tag names by using the tags array from the post json:

`tags: [12]`

```
export function getTag(id) {
    const url = "http://app.rguc.co.uk/?rest_route=/wp/v2/tags/" + id;
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data) {
                    dispatch(fetchSuccessTags(data));
                } else {
                    dispatch(fetchErrorTags(data));
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
}
```

When I combine them, how do I fire off a `fetch` for each post?

```
export function getDataAndTag() {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        return dispatch(fetchData()).then(() => {

            // For each post get tag names
            return dispatch(getTag(tagId));
        });
    };
}
```